# How to determine the parent widget of a tooltipdialog? - (Dojo 1.10+)

Tags: javascript, dojo

Is there a way to get the source widget that was clicked in order to show the tooltipdialog that drops down from it?

My goal is to have a button in the tooltipdialog that I can use to delete the parent widget.

So I place a widget in the tooltipdialog with one buton like this

```
  <input type="button" value="Delete" data-dojo-attach-event="click: delete" />
```

and in the widget I have my function delete

```
    deleteWidget: function (evt) {

        var thisDialog = this; 

        //do the delete 
    },
```

After I open the dialog and I click the button, in the debugger I inspect the event 'evt', as well as 'this', but I can't find anything in the list of properties and methods that indicates the source widget I clicked on.

Comment: I would suggest you try to avoid use of reserved keywords like `delete` in your java-script as they can cause bugs when building your application with dojo build tools.

Comment: @GibboK Thanks, I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the context of the event will be different than that of the widget. So the best option to achieve what you need is to attach the event in code and change the context using `lang.hitch`. Below is a skeleton code.

use data-dojo-attach-point instead

```
<input type="button" value="Delete" data-dojo-attach-point="deletebtn" />
```

The module here

```
define(....
   ...
   postCreate: function(){
       on(this.deletebtn, 'click', lang.hitch(this, "delete"));
       ....
   }

   delete:function(){
       //here this is the widget/module.
   }
}
```

UPDATE: dojo-attach-point might not work if you are setting the content of the TooltipDialog

Comment: I don't see how this can get you access to the widget that initiated the tool tip.  All I can get to regardless of the context, is the tool tip object itself., even with the using the attach point to trigger the even as in your code.

Comment: It depends, whether you initiate your tooltip within the module you have listening to the button click event. Otherwise take a look at this http://jsbin.com/xawajatase/20/edit?html,output  The main idea is to change the context of the click event to appropriate widget you need.